# Relevant Content Module Custom/Overwirete Theme

Tags: 7, theming

The module Relevant Content has a function called

theme_relevant_content_block

Which renders the nodes for the module. The comments say the following

"This is provided (the function) so that an item list is the default, however a themer can
easily override this to make a teaser list or table."

I'm not really sure how to use a 'themer' to overwrite this function.

Any pointers on how to do it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the themer. In your theme, copy that function, but call it YOURTHEME_relevant_content_block. Now change the function to output whatever you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not really sure where I'm supposed to place the THEME_relevant_content_block function. Does it go in a specific file under the themes/MYTHEME/ directory?

Comment: Yes. It goes inside a file called template.php

Comment: Check out the [Drupal Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme).  Documentation is relatively good for this :-)